# Proposta de Tradução "Moderator Agreement" para "Acordo de Moderador" e seu texto

Tags: debate, status-recusado, tradução, eleição, moderação

Achei este [contrato relativo ao ato de ser moderador no SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) o contrato está em inglês, e acredito que está na hora de traduzi-lo, portanto deixo minha proposta de tradução, fiz uma tradução direta adequando e complementando superficialmente algumas frases conforme meu entendimento do texto lido:

> ### Acordo de Moderador
>
> Para ter acesso as funções de moderador ♦, os [moderadores de nossa comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) devem analisar e aceitar os seguintes termos:
>
> ### O acordo:
>
> Eu reconheço e aceito que como um moderador da empresa Stack Exchange Inc.
>
>   i. Eu acatarei aos então correntes
>   [Termos de Serviços](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)
>   do Stack Overflow em Português, e outras políticas relativas a moderação disponibilizadas para mim,
>
>   ii. Eu reconheço que eu posso ter acesso a informações sobre os usuários do Stack Overflow em Português com potencial de identificar pessoas e que em relação a este acesso
>     a. Eu usarei tais informações somente conforme a
>     [Política de Privacidade](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy)
>     então corrente do Stack Overflow em Português,
>     b. Eu não revelarei estas informações a ninguém,
>     c. Eu não guardarei ou copiarei estas informações e
>     d. Eu somente usarei tais informações quando conectado ao Stack Overflow em Português como moderador para benefício do Stack Overflow em Português.
>
> Eu reconheço e aceito que eu sou um moderador em regime voluntário e  independente para o Stack Overflow em Português e eu não sou um empregado, funcionário, agente ou representante da empresa Stack Exchange Inc., e que não tenho autoridade de vincular a empresa Stack Exchange Inc. de nenhuma forma. A empresa Stack Exchange Inc. reserva-se o direito de finalizar meus privilégios como um moderador em qualquer momento sem aviso.

Comment: "Contrato" ou "Acordo"? No meu entendimento, todo contrato é um acordo, mas nem todo acordo é um contrato. [Referência](http://www.migalhas.com.br/LawEnglish/74,MI68214,91041-A+diferenca+entre+contrato+contract+e+agreement)

Comment: O item 8 do link sugerido, justifica bem o uso do termo **contrato**.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o item dois (2) da proposta de tradução herda tal reconhecimento, pois diz: "Eu estou de acordo com os termos de serviços então propostos pelo Stack Overflow em português"

Comment: Mantenha a mesma identação e numeração do original. Afinal, isto daí se propõe a ser apenas uma tradução, e não uma revisão ou reformatação.

Comment: Você aumentou o conteúdo do que está no item 8. No original não tem nada parecido com "qualquer direito contratual conforme as leis trabalhistas do país onde moro". Além disso, concordo com o @mgibsonbr. A tradução de "agreement" deveria ser "acordo", e não "contrato".

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu tentei melhorar a formatação e corrigi a indentação, no CTRL+C/V acabei engolindo-a. Mas ainda pode melhorar, quem puder contribuir editando, para ficar 100% serei grato.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, sim como eu disse é uma leitura do meu entendimento, e complementado como comentado na sugestão.

Comment: Sobre o uso do Acordo até fiquei tendencioso a mudar, já que no Brasil me parece adequado, mas alguém de portugal ou outro país que possa dar uma opinião?

Comment: @Delfino, dei uma editada para tentar deixar o mais fiel possível ao original. Se encontrar mais alguma coisa que esteja ou pareça estar em desacordo, eu volto a editar. Concordo que algumas das expressões que você usou até seriam melhores para a Stack Exchange do ponto de vista legal, mas infelizmente elas divergem do que está no original.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, também acho que ficou melhor.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Para a StackExchange o melhor - talvez até o mandatório - seria que os moderadores concordassem com o documento em inglês mesmo. Pois que eu saiba eles não têm negócios no Brasil ou em Portugal, o que vale mesmo é o que foi acordado na jurisdição deles. Eu acho interessante ter a tradução sim, mas de modo *"non-binding"*, apenas para melhor compreensão da comunidade (veja por exemplo [as "traduções não oficiais" do GNU GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/translations.html)).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Sim. O que quis dizer é que parte do texto que o Delfino havia colocado, até faria sentido estar no documento original em inglês, para o bem da Stack Exchange. Mas uma vez que lá não está, então não faz sentido que esteja aqui. Realmente, concordo que os moderadores devem celebrar o acordo com o texto em inglês e que a nossa tradução seja tão somente e nada mais do que uma tradução de um texto em inglês de caráter meramente informativo, e que apenas o original tenha algum valor prático.